# How to make an empty default case in switch expression in C#?

Tags: c#, default, switch-expression

How to make an empty default case in switch expression in C#?

I am talking about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) language feature.

Here is what I am trying:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = -2;
        var ignore = i switch {
            -1 => Console.WriteLine("foo"),
            -2 => Console.WriteLine("bar"),
            _ => ,
        };
    }
}
```

Also, I tried without the comma:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = -2;
        var ignore = i switch {
            -1 => Console.WriteLine("foo"),
            -2 => Console.WriteLine("bar"),
            _ =>
        };
    }
}
```

Still it does not want to compile. So, I tried to put an empty function:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i = -2;
        var ignore = i switch {
            -1 => Console.WriteLine("foo"),
            -2 => Console.WriteLine("bar"),
            _ => {}
        };
    }
}
```

And it still does not work.

Comment: can you just not remove the `_` default case? if you can 100% guarantee that switch will always match one of the previous cases.

Comment: Which C# version have you got this to compile in? It doesn't compile [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EccGge).

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, I updated my question. Could you try now, please?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, ok. It seems even the empty curly brackets do not work. I was wrong. :(

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` doesn't return anything when `switch` must return a value; it can be `var ignore = i switch {
        -1 => "foo",
        -2 => "ignore",
        _ => null
      };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are studing *expressions* `switch` expressions to be exact. All expressions must return a *value*; while `Console.WriteLine` being of type `void` returns *nothing*.

To fiddle with `switch` expressions you can try

```
public static void Main() {
  int i = -2;

  // switch expression: given i (int) it returns text (string)
  var text = i switch {
    -1 => "foo",
    -2 => "ignore",
     _ => "???" // or default, string.Empty etc.
  };

  Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Or putting expression into `WriteLine`:

```
public static void Main() {
  int i = -2;

  // switch expression returns text which is printed by WriteLine  
  Console.WriteLine(i switch {
    -1 => "foo",
    -2 => "ignore",
     _ => "???"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A switch *expression* must be able to evaluate to a value, as with all expressions.

For your purpose, a switch *statement* is the correct construct:

```
int i = -2;
switch (i)
{
    case -1:
        Console.WriteLine("foo");
        break;
    case -2:
        Console.WriteLine("bar");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That solves my problem and I appreciate your help. But I will accept another answer, since I like how he put the switch expression inside the `Console.WriteLine`. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @qqqqqqq Not at all :)